# How problematic is transitioning Augur's full-Serpent smart contract suite?

Tags: solidity, serpent, contract-invocation, augur

I read [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/46fz8f/ethereum_in_the_year_of_the_fire_monkey_can_you/) that Augur's smart contract suite is actually written in Serpent. I'm aware that it is a relatively well supported language at the moment (at least compared to Mutan and LLL), but given that [Solidity is thought to overtake all other languages at some point in the future](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-are-the-contract-languages/368#368), how problematic is the transition between the two languages likely to be for a platform like Augur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no [Fundamental limitations between Solidity and Serpent](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/126/fundamental-limitations-between-solidity-and-serpent), transitioning from Serpent to Solidity, **should be like porting from one language to another**, say Python to Javascript.  Code has to be rewritten, in some parts of the code the translation is easy, in other parts the porting may require more work: but it should be feasible and practicable.

Writing in Solidity is encouraged because it has a bigger team working on it, but Serpent is unlikely to be deprecated: it is still getting [commits from Vitalik Buterin](https://github.com/ethereum/serpent/commits/develop) from as recently as 6 days ago from this question being posted.  That commit was even titled [Added some more features for serenity.](https://github.com/ethereum/serpent/commit/003cdaca3bcf34dfa4a5f6baee29f19081c8bf1a)  Just make sure to check the [`develop` branch of Serpent](https://github.com/ethereum/serpent/tree/develop) (not the master branch).