# Ethereum development environment for Mac OSX El Capitan

Tags: dapp-development, mac-osx, installation, ide

What is the recommended development environment setup for developing Dapps on OSX El Capitan for a beginner?
What tools i need to get started with DAPP development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Read the tutorials at [ethereum.org](https://www.ethereum.org)
2. Understand Ethereum Clients and Smart Contract Languages
3. Smart Contract in-browser IDE [ReMix](https://remix.ethereum.org)

#### Development

You need an ethereum node to test against, i would recommend `geth` because its well documented

#### DApp-building Frameworks

**Trufle and Embark.** The one that got me started is Truffle. (Before Truffle I watched a group of smart student interns last summer code stuff for a sleepless hackathon (albeit with terrific results) and shrank back in fear. Then Truffle came along and did a lot of the nitty gritty stuff for you, so you can start writing-compiling-deploying-testing-building DApps right away.) Another very similar framework for building and testing DApps is Embark. Between those two, I’ve only used Truffle, but there are very successful DApp devs in both camps.

**APIs.** 
BlockApps.net is creating a RESTful API for DApps based on a Haskell node they run as a centralized service to save you the trouble of running a local Ethereum node. This departs from the completely decentralized model of DApps but is useful when running an Ethereum node locally isn’t realistic.

#### Development Tools

Community wiki [What are the development tools for Ethereum?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/2064/259)

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of [Create Eth App](https://github.com/paulrberg/create-eth-app)*

If what you're looking to build is a frontend app, I can recommend Create Eth App. It sets you up with an end-to-end environment that has everything you need to build a modern Ethereum-powered React app.

- Yarn Workspaces
- Create React App
- Boilerplate Subgraph
- Minimalist structure for managing smart contract ABIs and addresses

Try it out:

```sh
yarn create eth-app my-eth-app
```